# AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt-4

Estou fazendo uma pequena aplicação em Pyqt4 para entender o funcionamento.
Em uma determinada parte, estou usando uma função de callback para exibir numa `QLabel` o texto que é digitado no `QtextEdit`.

Esse texto deve ser aparado (remover espaços antes e depois da string).

Quando tentei usar a função `strip` presente em `str` do Python ocorreu o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'strip'

Pelo que eu entendi, em PyQt, a string não é um objeto `str` e sim `QString` e `QString` não possui o método `strip`.

Nesse caso, o que posso fazer para obter minha string tratada?

Código:

```
def onButtonOkClicked(self):

    def setText():
        text = self.line.toPlainText().strip();
        self.label.setText(text)

    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonOk, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), setText)
```

Comment: Onde está sendo usado o `strip()`?

Comment: Não uso muito Qt em python (só em C++ mesmo), mas o `QString` tem a função `trimmed`, que retira os espaços em branco no início e no fim. Seria equivalente ao `strip`? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#trimmed

Comment: @C.E.Gesser puts, deu certo. Pensei que ia ser resolvido de outra forma :p

Comment: @bigown custei a achar o código certo (o errado que gerou a pergunta). A ideia da pergunta surgiu ao mesmo tempo que eu editava aqui, kkkk

Comment: QString é diferente de String do python, acho que este é o motivo do problema, todavia ainda não entendi bem o objetivo, eu vou tentar rodar o pyqt aqui para testar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como disse na pergunta, o objetivo é passar o texto do QTextEdit para o Qlabel. Mas quero que no QLabel fique como o texto "limpinho"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só estou respondendo para explicar uma coisa:

O [`strip` (str.strip)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) é um método para strings do Python, que também é suportado por `bytes` (`bytes.strip([chars])` e `bytearray.strip([chars])`)

Já o `QString` é diferente de [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), resumindo ele é um objeto do Qt e não terá acesso aos mesmos métodos usados nas strings nativas do Python.

Você terá que usar os métodos do próprio `QString` conforme a documentação http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#public-functions

No caso como citado nas demais respostas, use o [`trimmed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#trimmed):

```
self.line.toPlainText().trimmed();
```

Vale notar que não existe equivalentes ao `ltrim()`, `rtrim()` ou passar argumentos para mudar o que tipo de caractere que deseja aparar, como ocorre no `strip([chars])`

```
print("---foobar----".strip('-'))
```

que resultaria em `foobar`, então se desejar certas operações que existem em `str()` use apenas `str` e depois converta para `QString` (quando necessário).

Answer (score 5):

Pode usar [`simplified()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#simplified) da própria `QString`. É um método mais limitado, mas pode funcionar. Dependendo do que quer pode ser usada a [`trimmed()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#trimmed) também.

Pode usar [`replace(QString(" "), QString(""))`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-8) se quiser outros caracteres.

Embora sugiro evitar, também pode converter para a *string* do Python:

```
str(text)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Convert.py).

As duas codificações são completamente diferentes, se ficar convertendo de uma para outra toda hora desperdiçará recursos. Quando se usa Qt a ideia é ficar o máximo possível com elae só converter quando é estritamente necessário.

Comment: Tem uma parte da aplicação que, para definir o texto como vazio, eu estou fazendo `self.line.setText("")`. Nesse caso, o recomendável é usar `self.line.setText(QtGui.QString(""))`?

Comment: Eu acho que sim, melhor não misturar formatos de texto. Se não me engano tem como criar uma `QString` sem passar pelo construtor, mas faz tempo que não mexo com Qt já não me lembro mais. Acho até que é coisa mais ou menos nova.

Answer (score 3):

A classe `QString` possui a função `trimmed()`, que retorna uma nova `QString` com os espaços em branco removidos do início e do fim do texto.

Documentação da versão Pyhton: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstring.html#trimmed

Documentação da versão C++: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#trimmed